# SQL Incorrect syntax when creating pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

When running this code:

```
drop table #yt

create table #yt 
(
    [Country] NVARCHAR(MAX) , 
    [USRankTitle] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    [xCount] int
);

INSERT INTO #yt ([Country], [USRankTitle], [xCount]) 
    SELECT 
        [Country], [USRanktitle],
        COUNT(USranktitle) AS xcount 
    FROM 
        UMADUserAccounts 
    GROUP BY
        Country, USRankTitle

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = 'select USRankTitle from #yt group by USRankTitle order by 
USRankTitle'

SET @query = 'SELECT * from (
            select Country, USRankTitle 
            from #yt group by country,USRankTitle
        ) x
        pivot (
            sum(xCount) 
            for USRankTitle in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p' 

EXECUTE(@query)
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I've checked the code and tried various different things, but can't seem to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before `execute(@query)` add `PRINT @query` and check with the result query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the `SELECT` query for `@cols` as below and try:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(USRankTitle)
            FROM #yt
            GROUP BY USRankTitle
            ORDER BY USRankTitle
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Also add `PRINT @query` before `execute(@query)` and can check the composed query.